# Load Different config file based on domain name

Tags: php

I want to be able to load a different config file based on the domain name using purely PHP.

Currently my config file loads using the following

```
# Look for a config.php in the /themes/themeName/ folder
if ( ! defined('MULTI') && file_exists($tmp = WWW_ROOT . '/themes/' . $CONFIG['theme'] . '/config.php') ) {
```

But i need to be able to add if domain is domain1.com load config from /theme/domain1 or if it is domain2.com load from /theme/domain2 and if it is not either of these domains loads from /theme/default.

This is used when a domain name is parked ontop of another domain so the content is all the same except for the config files.

I was thinking something along the lines of

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']="domain1.com")
else if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']="domain2.com")
else
```

Just not sure how to properly format that or it that would be the best way to do it.

Comment: Why not just make a domain-specific `config.php` file that you upload to each domain?

Comment: All the domains have the same content on them just miner things such as Ad Code Placement/Pub IDs need to be different per domain. But i would like to be able to have all these domains load from 1 source so i can have lots of domains all parked onto 1 domain.

Answer (score 1):

```
$themes_path=array( 
'domain1.com'=>'foldername1',
'domain2.com'=>'foldername2'
);

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) && file_exists(WWW_ROOT . '/themes/' . $themes_path[$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']] . '/config.php'){
include(WWW_ROOT . '/themes/' . $themes_path[$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']] . '/config.php');
}
```

i think direct include $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] not very good.

Comment: Im actually going to use the first part you posted above with the other answer to this question cause i like listing domains and folder names as you have done. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) && file_exists(WWW_ROOT . '/themes/' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/config.php')
    include(WWW_ROOT . '/themes/' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/config.php');
else
    include(WWW_ROOT . '/themes/default/config.php');
```

Comment: This looks perfect, it should load the config file if it exists for the domain otherwise load the default.